# Need help correcting python code for owm forecast

Tags: python, linux, openweathermap

There is such an application https://github.com/atx/AsteroidOSLinux to synchronize asteroidos with linux. And there is a problem with OWM synchronization, the application has not been updated for a long time and I suspect that there were some changes on the part of owm, but I am far from programming, and I ask for your help.

UPD: When running the script, the following message appears: "Weather update error with <class 'AttributeError'>

Here is part of the code from example.py:

```
args = parser.parse_args()

ADDRESS = "43:43:A0:12:1F:AC"
OWM_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
OWM_LOCATION = "Prague"

app = asteroid.app.App(ADDRESS, verbose=args.verbose)

app.register_module(ReconnectModule(timeout_base=10))
app.register_module(TimeSyncModule())
app.register_module(NotifyModule())
app.register_module(OWMModule(api_key=OWM_KEY, location=OWM_LOCATION))
app.register_module(MPDModule())
```

And this part of the code is probably responsible for OWM, modules.py:

```
class OWMModule(Module):

    defconfig = {"update_interval": 2 * 60 * 60 }

    def register(self, app):
        super(OWMModule, self).register(app)
        self._update_weather()
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(self.config["update_interval"], self._update_weather)

    def _update_weather(self):
        try:
            owm = pyowm.OWM(self.config["api_key"])
            # TODO: Eventually, autodetecting the location would be nice
            forecast = owm.daily_forecast(self.config["location"]).get_forecast()
            preds = WeatherPredictions.from_owm(forecast)
            self.asteroid.update_weather(preds)
            self.logger.info("Weather update sent")
        except Exception as e:
            # We can't str the exception directly, because a bug in PyOWM python3
            # support would lead to another exception
            self.logger.error("Weather update failed with %s" % type(e))
        return True
```

Thanks in advance for any hints

I tried to study this issue in the asteroidos branch , but so far everything is in vain

UPD2: After adding the line self.logger.exception('weather update'), the following message appeared:

```
~/AsteroidOSLinux/example.py
[INF] Time synchronized
[ERR] Weather update failed with <class 'AttributeError'>
[ERR] weather update
Traceback 9most revent call last):
   File "~/AsteroidOSLinux/asteroid/module.py", line 152, in _update_weather
      forecast = owm.daily_forecast(self.config["location"]).get_forecast()
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'OWM' object has no attribute 'daily_forecast'
```

[image]

Comment: *there is a problem* -- WHAT problem?  You don't expect us to guess, do you?

Comment: Please accept my apologies, apparently while I was writing the text I was thinking and missed this detail. When running the script, everything is triggered except "weather" and the following message appears: "Weather update failed with <class 'AttributeError'>

Comment: More information is needed about the AttributeError, including the full message and traceback. To get that, add `self.logger.exception('weather update')` after the `self.logger.error` line, run it again, edit the question, and copy-paste the full, multiline error message.

Comment: @pts After adding the line self.logger.exception('weather update'), the following message appeared:  ~/AsteroidOSLinux/example.py
[INF] Time synchronized
[ERR] Weather update failed with <class 'AttributeError'>
[ERR] weather update
Traceback 9most revent call last):
   File "~/AsteroidOSLinux/asteroid/module.py", line 152, in _update_weather
      forecast = owm.daily_forecast(self.config["location"]).get_forecast()
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'OWM' object has no attribute 'daily_forecast'

Comment: The last error line is most relevant here. What makes you believe that the .get_forecast() method should exist? What documentation are you following? Have you installed the correct version of the software? Is there an FAQ? Have you contacted the developers of the software?

Comment: Note that both pyowm v2 and pyowm v3 now exist and they are incompatible.  You need to make sure you are using the one your sample expects.